# HttpClient Shared Connection manager

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

Env : HttpClient 4.4.

In HttpClientBuilder class, I can see following code,

```
if (!this.connManagerShared){

   // ...some code

   if (this.evictExpiredConnections || this.evictIdleConnections) {

            final IdleConnectionEvictor connectionEvictor = new IdleConnectionEvictor((HttpClientConnectionManager) connManagerCopy,
                    this.maxIdleTime > 0L ? this.maxIdleTime : 10L, this.maxIdleTimeUnit != null ? this.maxIdleTimeUnit : TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            closeablesCopy1.add(new Closeable()
            {
                public void close() throws IOException
                {
                    connectionEvictor.shutdown();
                }
            });
            connectionEvictor.start();
    }
     // ...some code
}
```

I am not able to correlate these two conditions.

Why would you not have IdleConnectionEvictor, if you are using a shared connectionmanager ?

Answer (score 0):

If one creates multiple instances of `HttpClient` sharing a single connection pool, one would likely want to have only instance of `IdleConnectionEvictor` as well, would one not? What would be the point of multiple `IdleConnectionEvictor` contending for the connection pool lock to evict idle connections, when one instance would perfectly suffice?